# How Much does it cost to buy Cross-Org Adapter for Salesforce Connect for Unlimited Edition

Tags: lightning-connect, salesforce2salesforce

We are considering replacing `Salesforce to Salesforce` usage by  `Cross-Org Adapter for Salesforce Connect` and use it for other cases.
It is provided for free in `Developer Edition` but in client organization it is only available for an extra cost [per documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=xorg_adapter_about.htm&type=5).

Does anyone know how much does it cost to buy this feature before we suggest it to client?

Where I can find information about that?

Comment: Can you ask your client's account executive?  If they don't know who it is, they can find out via Setup > Checkout

Comment: Pricing is available from Sales, and may depend on a pricing matrix. Whatever we tell you would not be binding, and may not reflect the amount you would be quoted depending on your situation (edition, number of licenses, special promos, etc). You should definitely go to Sales and ask.

Comment: Got it. My client refused to even consider buying this option. thanks.

Comment: @Patlatus What was the reason for refusal? High cost of the adapter?

Comment: @RajeshShah I misguided them assuming that Cross-org adapter is free, so they just didn't want to consider this option when I found out that it is available only to additional price

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there additional cost for lightning connect/external objects?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81446/is-there-additional-cost-for-lightning-connect-external-objects)