# How can we sync the objects across 2 Salesforce ORGS?

Tags: sync, data-synchronization, salesforce-connect

Here is the context:

I have a ORG which has a lot of records of many objects. I want to sync these objects to the new ORG. Going forward if any record is added/deleted/updated from OLD/New Salesforce ORG, then the change needs to be applied in both the ORGS. Please help me in achieving this.

Approach Tried:

I have tried Salesforce Cross ORG adapter for syncing the data, but here we need to create a external object in the Subscriber ORG. Also the object API Name of the external object is different from the object from which it was synced from the Publisher/Provider ORG. Hence this approach needs a apex code change.

Comment: Take a look at [Data Integration decision guide](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/data-integration), it covers the options.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using  [salesforce to salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.business_network_intro.htm&type=5) feature with out coding.

Comment: While this is an option, it's a legacy option that has been in maintenance mode for many years. It has quite a few limitations: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306135/estimate-effort-of-a-salesforce-to-salesforce-project

Comment: Thanks @Ankaiah Bandi. But seems like Salesforce doesn't recommend to use this.