# Forwarding accounts back to the source org

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I've found an odd behavior when studying about Salesforce to Salesforce Integration.

- Dunder Mifflin and Vance Refrigeration mutually publish and subscribe to Accounts from each other. They both are subscribing to Account Name and Account Type fields.
- Michael Scott (Dunder Mifflin) pushed his Account (Staples) to Vance Refrigeration.
- Bob Vance (Vance Refrigeration) changed Staples' Account Type and tried to push back to Dunder Mifflin. He selects Staples' account record on Accounts List View and, after clicking on "Forward To Connections" button, Bob can't proceed because he gets a message saying "You can only forward records that you or your subordinates own. System administrators can forward all records."

[image]

- Now comes the odd behavior: if Bob selects Staples' record **AND** McDonalds' (an account created by him in Vance Refrigeration Org) record then Dunder Mifflin connection appears and he is allowed to push **BOTH RECORDS** despite the same message showing up.

[image]

**I haven't found explanation to this behavior. Is it a bug or there is an explanation I am not aware of?**

Thanks in advance,

PS: Kudos to those who recognized people involved in this test. :)

Comment: Not an answer to your question but as a FYI re: S2S - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306135/estimate-effort-of-a-salesforce-to-salesforce-projec

Comment: Thanks anyway for sharing!