# Salesforce to Salesforce only available in Salesforce Classic - What exactly does that mean

Tags: integration, salesforce-to-salesforce

As per Salesforce Documentation Salesforce to Salesforce Integation Feature is only available in Salesforce Classic. So my question is: What exactly does that mean?

- Do I have to make the configuration in Salesforce Classic Setup? Not nice, but acceptable, because it's far away from daily business and more or less a one-time configuration job
- Or does that even mean, that objects replicated via Salesforce to Salesforce are only visibile to the end users in Salesforce Classic?
- If the latter comes true, what are alternatives despite from Custom Apex Code?
  Any tipps are highliy appreciated.

Thx a lot!

Comment: https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306135/estimate-effort-of-a-salesforce-to-salesforce-project/ are good reads

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

- [Setup and Config](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.business_network_configure.htm&type=5); eg. subscribing to objects, field mapping) (Classic only)
- [Buttons to forward records to remote system](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.business_network_assign_records.htm&type=5) (Classic only)
- [Buttons to Accept records from remote system](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.business_network_lead_inbox.htm&type=5) (Classic only)
- [Objects replicated visible in Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.business_network_managing_leads.htm&type=5): YES, w/ exceptions:

> NOTE For existing S2S customers, records your connections share are available in the new user interface as long as their object type is supported in Lightning Experience; however, the Created By and Modified By fields are no longer displayed.

So, basically, unless you've configured for 100% automated forwarding/accepting of records, users will need to switch to Classic.

Alternatives are covered in the [Salesforce Architects Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) article. The pros and cons of each approach will need to be evaluated by your enterprise as to which is best.

> The Salesforce to Salesforce product has reached its end of life. Salesforce to Salesforce made it easy for partners working together to sell to and support joint customers, but Salesforce will be investing in bringing more innovation to other tools. Moving forward, the following approaches are recommended for sharing data between Salesforce organizations.

Comment: Thanks very much for your valuable answer. The only thing I cannot really understand, is the following statement in the Notes of the SFDC docu:
however, the Created By and Modified By fields are no longer displayed.

Comment: It means that because the object shared to remote system 2 was created by the Salesforce2Salesforce automated user, that user is not shown in the CreatedBy field within remote system 2

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'll just create a PoC and see what goes and what does not go ;-)